# Delete leftover old files after upgrading Moodle

Tags: file, moodle

I need a way to figure out which files are left over after upgrading Moodle to a newer version.

I have:

- Old version + many plugins
- New version
- Merged version

In the new version some files have been removed but they still exist in the merged version.

I could start with the new version and copy all the plugins but many are in different sub folders which will take too long.

Is there a quick way to list or delete these left over files?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a clone of Moodle in a separate folder.

```
git clone git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git moodleclone
```

Then check the version of Moodle in `/version.php` in your code - look for `$release  = '2.x.x`. Then checkout the exact version of the Moodle clone

```
cd moodleclone
git checkout v2.x.x
```

Then use Meld to compare the 2 folders. http://meldmerge.org/

```
meld ../moodleclone ../yourmoodleversion
```

This will then show any code differences between the 2. You can see if its an official Moodle plugin or one that has been added.

It would be better if you use the uninstall plugin option via site admin -> plugins because it should remove any data in your database too. You might also want to do a clean install in a new database using the Moodle clone, then dump and compare the database structure from the clone and your code to see if there are any database changes.